# how to install Wimax Dongle over Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, usb, drivers, wimax

i have Asus Wimax Dongle
and it has an Independence software from the Asus company
requires user name and password
and its running will over windows 7

now i've tried ubuntu 10.10
but nothing happens when i plug the dongle into usb.

in windows if you plugs it for the first time, an application wizard begins 
and you can find a virtual cd in my computer
but i cant find it in Ubuntu

now i would install it over ubuntu, how?

toast for all

Answer (score 1):

To get the driver installed for Wimax, type the following using the Terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T` to open it).

Type in the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install madwimax
```

Answer (score 0):

There're no publicly available drivers so far for many WiMAX USB dongles (for my case, Malaysian, Yes "Go" manufactured by Infomark, using GCT chip).

You can do [`usb_modeswitch`](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/) (by default, it is enabled, see `/etc/usb_modeswitch.conf`) to convert it from storage to a GSM modem. But that's the farthest you can (I could) go.